# Jquery - load page with slowly and with loading gif effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my page loads with loading effect.

A small example about what im talking:

```
<a href="#" id="a1">PAGE1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">PAGE2</a>
<a href="#" id="a3">PAGE3</a>

<div id="page1">Hey this is page 1</div>
<div id="page2">Hey this is page 2</div>
<div id="page3">Hey this is page 3</div>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#page1").hide();
   $("#page2").hide();
   $("#page3").hide();

    $("#a1").click(function(){
        $("#page1").show();
        return false;
    });

    $("#a2").click(function(){
        $("#page2").show();
        return false;
    });

    $("#a3").click(function(){
        $("#page3").show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Hope you understand what im talking about, and is it posible to make it slower for load? I mean smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery you could use **[.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)** instead of `show()` check example below.

**NOTES :**

- It's better if you could use one event instead of repeating the same code for every new link, if you don't want to toggle between `show/hide` of the page you could use `fadeIn()`.
- You could use comma separator to trigger the same method on multiple selectors :

  ```
  $("#page1,#page2,#page3").hide();
  ```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
  $("#page1,#page2,#page3,#loading").hide();

  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loading').show();

    switch($(this).attr('id')){
      case 'a1':
        $("#page1").fadeToggle("slow",function(){ $('#loading').hide() });
      break;
      case 'a2':
        $("#page2").fadeToggle(2000,function(){ $('#loading').hide() });
      break;
      case 'a3':
        $("#page3").fadeToggle("fast",function(){ $('#loading').hide() });
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="loading" src="http://www.tbaf.org.tw/event/2016safe/imgs/loader1.gif" width="250">
<a href="#" id="a1">PAGE1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">PAGE2</a>
<a href="#" id="a3">PAGE3</a>

<div id="page1">Hey this is page 1</div>
<div id="page2">Hey this is page 2</div>
<div id="page3">Hey this is page 3</div>
```

Comment: and how to insert loading gif?? before the fadein??

Comment: Check my update, better if you could use `fadeToggle()` callback to hide the loading gif so you could parameter the speed like you want (see my example) and the gif follow the used animation.

Comment: merci wld bladi :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#page1").hide();
  $("#page2").hide();
  $("#page3").hide();
  $("#loadingGif").hide();

  function anim(id) {
    $("#loadingGif").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#loadingGif").hide();
      $(id).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 400)
  }
  $("#a1").click(function() {

    anim("#page1");
    return false;
  });

  $("#a2").click(function() {
    anim("#page2");
    return false;
  });

  $("#a3").click(function() {
    anim("#page3");
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
#loadingGif {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="a1">PAGE1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">PAGE2</a>
<a href="#" id="a3">PAGE3</a>

<div id="page1">Hey this is page 1</div>
<div id="page2">Hey this is page 2</div>
<div id="page3">Hey this is page 3</div>

<img id="loadingGif" src="http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="200" height="200" />
```

You can use Jquery's fadeIn

> $(selector).fadeIn(speed,callback);

You can read more at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

and here http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: hello sir, but how can i start it with loading image when the link is clicked then fadein??

Answer (score 1):

You can create one div called `preloader` and when you click on link you can use `fadeIn()` then you load your content and then you `fadeOut` preloader with slight `delay`

```js
var preloader = $('.preloader');
preloader.hide();

$('a').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
 
  preloader.fadeIn(function() {
    $(target).siblings().css('opacity', 0);
    $(target).css('opacity', 1);
  }).delay(1500).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-target="#page1">PAGE1</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#page2">PAGE2</a>
<a href="#" data-target="#page3">PAGE3</a>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content" id="page1">Hey this is page 1</div>
  <div class="content" id="page2">Hey this is page 2</div>
  <div class="content" id="page3">Hey this is page 3</div>
</div>

<div class="preloader">
  <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/12755/screenshots/1037374/hex-loader2.gif" alt="">
</div>
```